# After successfully running hello world program, experimenting with changes quickly

Tags: android

I have run my hello world program, got the emulator to come up successfully, waited and waited and waited patiently for the emulator to display my message. Now I want to experiment further. Do I have to go through the whole waiting process again or is there a quicker way to see the results now that the emulator is up and my app appears on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the emulator open - it's a bit quicker the second time round. If it's still too slow consider more RAM and an SSD. Failing that, buy a phone for the quickest load times.